# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0."

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization, urlsession

I know there are multiple posts out there with same error and I have tried the possible solutions posted in there, but nothing is helping.

Basically I have an URL of which I have to remove last "/1" of the URL and append token to it and then run/load the URL and want the response back in JSON.

Below is my main URL and the code too. "test" in the URL stands for a specific domain name and when I open the URL in the browser I do see the contents of it / URL opening successfully.

**Main URL** - `"https://services.test.com/sK3mvyHqwTrzhjjo/test/rest/services/Booking_Test/Server/1"`

**Tokenized URL** - `"https://services.test.com/sK3mvyHqwTrzhjjo/test/rest/services/Booking_Test/Server/?token=Po-2mlbjbyZ-HTrxdxWjNwMec3uUJpAy6mSvdY6mThv3RznzLihdTRfUrO2LLWtCQzyskbk2A61gelfXH7IyiANAbFq8PEWJ8f0qud6JTOW3r9PXDtkOFHNEYDKzokW8sBD_MtMde_YZZiwydxDM8sA0hTkOrR2yKjRpbn5kxBH8rGM-JYgLk3BLUOcvzrPC9KzAOJGhGJifh5dN03YjX7Zz4FYJhJPBeiVeZSQ2-XHbRK9yn_E2XZ62-ljPX2ZO"`

***Code:***

```
if let url = URL(string: baseURL!)?.deletingLastPathComponent() {
    let tokenizedURL = addToken(url: url)
    var request = URLRequest(url:tokenizedURL);
    request.httpMethod = "GET";
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    firstly {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: request)
    }.compactMap {
        try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: $0.data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
    }.done { dictionary in
        //…
    }.catch {_ in
        // `JSONError`
    }
}
```

So far I have tried - `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: $0.data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary` and `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: $0.data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]` and still I keep getting the same error.

Not sure what's wrong here and where do I need to make changes. Any idea what does the error mean exactly?

Comment: Print `String(data: $0.data, encoding: .utf8)`. Then check if the response is valid JSON before attempting to serialize it assuming it is. There are plenty online JSON validator.

Comment: Unrelated but `.allowFragments` is pointless if the expected type is a collection type. Remove the `options` parameter. And the `URLRequest` is not necessary. `GET` is the default anyway and the header is redundant.

Comment: There might be a problem with json data that you are getting in response. 
I'll suggest, try to hit the same API with postman or any other API tester.